# Urysohn's Lemma: Proof

Tags: general-topology

Given a normal space $\Omega$.

> Then closed sets can be separated continuously:
>   $$h\in\mathcal{C}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}):\quad h(A)\equiv0,\,h(B)\equiv1\quad(A,B\in\mathcal{T}^\complement)$$
>   Especially, it can be chosen as a bump: $0\leq h\leq1$

Though the idea is very clear it can be strikingly technical.

The goal here is to crystalize out the most lucid version!

*Disclaimer: This is a record for future threads.*

Comment: I like the proof given by Munkres, especially because of the introduction: "Now we come to the first deep theorem of the book, [...] Why do we call the Urysohn lemma a "deep" theorem? Because its proof involves
a really original idea, [...] But the Urysohn lemma is on a different level. It would take considerably
more originality than most of us possess to prove this lemma unless we were given
copious hints!"

Comment: In Kolmogrov Real Analysis, the chapter on normal topologies has as a problem "prove Urysohn Lemma". No hints. I was so depressed about not getting it until I read this posting

Comment: [On the rationals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31327/in-the-proof-of-urysohns-lemma-why-are-the-open-sets-indexed-by-dyadic-numbers?rq=1), [Normality as intermediate open set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2018740/understanding-urysohn-lemma),[Showing continuity in Step-4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340514/in-step-4-of-munkres-proof-of-urysohn-lemma-how-does-he-prove-the-continuity/341019#341019)

Comment: [Set used for continuity in step-4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4514078/a-question-about-proof-of-urysohn-lemma)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$I prefer a more topological proof.

Let $D$ be the set of [dyadic rationals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational) in $[0,1]$. We shall construct a family $\{U(d):d\in D\}$ of sets $A \subseteq U(d) \subseteq \Omega\setminus B$, all open with the possible exception of $U(0)$, satisfying the condition that $\cl U(d_0)\subseteq U(d_1)$ whenever $d_0,d_1\in D$ and $d_0<d_1$.

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+_0$ = set of non-negative integers let $D_n  = \{\frac{k}{2^n} : k\in\{0,\ldots,2^n\} \}$. We have $D_{n} \subseteq D_{n+1}$ and $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty D_n = D$. We shall construct the desired $U(d)$ inductively for $d \in D_n$.

For $n = 0$ let $U(0)=A$ and $U(1)=\Omega\setminus B$. Note that $U(0)$ is closed, but in general not open.

Now suppose the $U(d)$ have been constructed for $d \in D_n$. By normality, for each $k\in\{0,\ldots,2^n\}$ there is an open $U\left(\frac{2k+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)$ such that

$$\cl U\left(\frac{k}{2^n}\right)=\cl U\left(\frac{2k}{2^{n+1}}\right)\subseteq U\left(\frac{2k+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\subseteq\cl U\left(\frac{2k+1}{2^{n+1}}\right)\subseteq U\left(\frac{k+1}{2^n}\right)\;.$$

Let

$$h:\Omega\to[0,1]:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }x\notin U(1)\\
\inf\{d\in D:x\in U(d)\},&\text{otherwise}\;.
\end{cases}$$

Clearly $h[A]=\{0\}$ and $h[B]=\{1\}$, so it only remains to show that $h$ is continuous. First note that if $r\in D$ and $x\in U(r)$, then $h(x)\le r$, while if $x\in\Omega\setminus\cl U(r)$ then $h(x)\ge r$. Now let $x\in\Omega$ and $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary.

- If $h(x)=0$, choose $r\in D$ so that $0<r<\epsilon$; then $V=U(r)$ is an open nbhd of $x$ such that $h[V]\subseteq[0,\epsilon)$.
- If $h(x)=1$, choose $r\in D$ so that $1-\epsilon<r<1$; then $V=\Omega\setminus\cl U(r)$ is an open nbhd of $x$ such that $h[V]\subseteq(1-\epsilon,1]$.
- If $0<h(x)<1$, choose $r,s\in D$ so that $h(x)-\epsilon<r<h(x)<s<h(x)+\epsilon$; then $V=U(s)\setminus\cl U(r)$ is an open nbhd of $x$ such that $h[V]\subseteq(h(x)-\epsilon,h(x)+\epsilon)$.

Thus, $h$ is continuous at every point of $\Omega$.

Comment: Can you explain the main difference of both constructions? *(It seems to me they're basically the same, or?)*

Comment: @Freeze_S: The underlying idea is the same; the details and point of view are not. Rudin’s version is, unsurprisingly, the sort of argument that an analyst would naturally make; the other version avoids semicontinuity altogether. Rudin also leaves quite a bit of detail in the construction of the $V_s$ for the reader to fill in.

Comment: You claim "by induction one can define inductively" while this proof is actually constructive (but only does it for a sufficient subset of the rationals); it's the proof I have been taught as well. It's very direct, no extra notions necessary.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: Yes the iteration is done differently but after all both give rise to some sort of dense chain of neighborhoods, or?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: But isn't the constructed bump actually the same comparing this one similar to the one on proofwiki  with the lower approximation by Rudin? Rudin just gives an intermediate step by semi continuity, or?

Comment: @Freeze_S: Might be, might not be: it depends on the choice of sets $U(r)$ and $V_s$. For that matter, two instantiations of either of the constructions could yield different functions, though all would have the desired properties. But that’s beside the point: the point is that the proofs are very different in style. And I much prefer the more topologically written version.

Comment: After all both are nice! :) (+1)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Ah I guess you mean the way of how to prove continuity, ok.

Comment: @Freeze_S: Yes, though I also think that using just the dyadic rationals makes the construction of the open sets just a little simpler.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: The iteration in both cases is done iteratively so constructive and work for all subset of the rationals not only sufficient ones as the dyadics: The main point is to consider a countable set! The construction then works in all cases **exactly** the same: $q_{i_-}\leq q_{n+1}\leq q_{i_+}:\overline{V_{i_-}}\subseteq V_{n+1}\subseteq\overline{V_{n+1}}\subseteq V_{i_+}$ More precisely the choice is done explicitely by: $q_{i_-}:=\max\{q_i\leq q_{n+1}:1\leq i\leq n\},q_{i_+}:=\min\{q_{n+1}\leq q_i:1\leq i\leq n\}$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I see now why you not only think it is more direct but even more topological: In all three cases one has instantenously the open sets from the previous iteration. I'm sorry for the disruption. =(

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Would you mind if I outsource the construction of the chain of open sets into the question? *(This way your answer focuses on the topological proof of continuity.)*

Comment: I was confused with the continuity part of this proof. seems the definition used here is like **Any point $x_0\in X$, and any open interval $(c, d)$ containing the point $f(x_0)$, then there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ with $f(U)\subseteq (c,d)$**. But doesn't we have to show the preimage of open is open? @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory: It’s a basic fact (and easy to prove) that the boldface condition is equivalent to the statement that $f^{-1}[(c,d)]$ is open.

Comment: From $f^{-1}[(c, d)]$ to $f(U) \subseteq(c, d)$ is easy becasuse open set contain ngbd. But from $f(U) \subseteq(c, d)$ how I argue that $f^{-1}[(c, d)]$ is open? @BrianM.Scott Here I was stuck. Let $X=\{0,1,2\}$ with topology $\tau_{X}=\{\varnothing,\{0\},\{1,2\}, X\}$, and $Y=\{a, b, c\}$ with the discrete topology. The map $0 \mapsto a, 1 \mapsto b, 2 \mapsto c$ is continuous at 0 , but the preimage of the open set $\{a, b\}$ containing $a$ is $\{0,1\}$, which is not open. It seems only ngbd definition is working but I really confused with open and $f(U)\subseteq (c,d)$ one.

Comment: @WhyMeasureTheory: Let $X$ be a topological space and $f:X\to\Bbb R$; then $f$ is continuous iff for each $x\in X$ and open interval $(c,d)$ around $f(x)$ there is an open nbhd $U$ of $x$ such that $f[U]\subseteq(c,d)$. For the non-trivial direction suppose that the condition is satisfied, and let $(c,d)$ be any open interval in $\Bbb R$. Let $W=f^{-1}[(c,d)]$; then each $x\in W$ has an open nbhd $U_x$ such that $f[U_x]\subseteq(c,d)$. Clearly for each $x\in W$ we have $x\in U_x\subseteq W$, so $W=\bigcup_{x\in W}U_x$, and $W=f^{-1}[(c,d)]$ is therefore open in $X$.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: This is community wiki; feel free to correct, edit, expand etc.! ;)*

*(This is a slight modification taken from Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis.)*

Regard for simplicity:
$$C:=B\subseteq A^\complement=:U$$

Denote for construction the rationals:
$$S:=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$$

By normality one can find inductively open $V_s$ for $s \in S$ such that
$$C\subseteq V_1, \quad \overline{V_0}\subseteq U,\quad V_s\subseteq\overline{V_{s'}} \text{ for } s>s' .$$

Consider the upper and lower semicontinuous functions:
$$\underline{h}_s:=s\chi_{V_s}:\quad\underline{h}_s^{-1}(a,\infty)=\varnothing,V_s,\Omega\in\mathcal{T}$$
$$\overline{h}_s:=(1-s)\chi_{\overline{V_s}}+s:\quad\overline{h}_s^{-1}(-\infty,b)=\varnothing,\overline{V_s}^\complement,\Omega\in\mathcal{T}$$

Pointwise suprema resp. infima preserve lower resp. upper semicontinuity:
$$\underline{h}:=\sup_{s\in S}\underline{h}_s:\quad\underline{h}^{-1}(a,\infty)=\{\omega:\underline{h}(\omega)>a\}=\bigcup_{s\in S}\{\omega:\underline{h}_s(\omega)>a\}=\bigcup_{s\in S}\underline{h}_s^{-1}(a,\infty)\in\mathcal{T}$$
$$\overline{h}:=\inf_{s\in S}\overline{h}_s:\quad\overline{h}^{-1}(-\infty,b)=\{\omega:\overline{h}(\omega)<b\}=\bigcup_{s\in S}\{\omega:\overline{h}_s(\omega)<b\}=\bigcup_{s\in S}\overline{h}_s^{-1}(-\infty,b)\in\mathcal{T}$$

They approach each other as by contradiction:
$$\underline{h}(\omega)<s<s'<\overline{h}(\omega)\implies\omega\in\overline{V_{s'}}\subseteq V_s\not\owns\omega$$
$$\underline{h}_s(\omega)>\overline{h}_{s'}(\omega)\implies\omega\in V_s\subseteq\overline{V_s}\subseteq V_{s'}\subseteq\overline{V_{s'}}\not\owns\omega\quad(s>s')$$

So they together become continuous:
$$h:=\overline{h}=\underline{h}:\quad h^{-1}(c-\varepsilon,c+\varepsilon)=h^{-1}(-\infty,c+\varepsilon)\cup h^{-1}(c-\varepsilon,\infty)\in\mathcal{T}$$

Thus the limiting function is the desired bump:
$$h(C)\subseteq h(V_1)\equiv1,\,h(U^\complement)\subseteq h(\overline{V_0}^\complement)\equiv0$$

Comment: I strongly dislike $\ni$, but if you insist on using it, `\not\ni` works quite well for its negation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: But there's no combined version? *Sorry for the early congrats. oO*

Comment: I’m not aware of one but I’m far from expert. (+300k? Not there yet: André Nicolas is the only so far.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Ah great I was looking for something like '\not' already for long time. Thanks! :)

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

(Various versions of Urysohn’s lemma)
Dugundji = Dugundji, J.: Topology, Boston: Allyn and Bacon, 1966.
Pervin = Pervin, W.J.: Foundations of General Topology, New York, Academic Press, 1964.
Pontryagin = Pontryagin, L.: Topological Groups, translated from the Russian by Emma Lehmer, Princeton: Princeton
University Press, 1946.
Rudin = Rudin, W.: Real and Complex Analysis, 2nd ed., New York: McGraw-Hill, 1974.
A. Pontryagin [p.46, l.$-$16]: $R$ is a compact regular topological space satisfying the second axiom of countability; the key ideas: Pontryagin [p.46, l.$-$11--l.$-$8].
B. Dugundji [p.146, Theorem 4.1 (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2)]: $Y$ is normal.
C. Pervin [p.158, Urysohn's lemma]: $X$ is normal.
D. Rudin [p.40, l.14]: $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space.
Remark 1. The proof of A is the primitive model. Regular Lindel$\ddot{\text{o}}$f $\Rightarrow$ Normal [Dugundji [p.311, diagram]], so $B\Rightarrow A$. Thus, B is stronger than A. A stronger hypothesis implies stronger result, so $\bar{G}_r\cap F=\varnothing$ [Pontryagin [p.47, l.8]] is stronger than $U(r)\cap B=\varnothing$  [Dugundji [p.147, l.13]]. The proof method given in A and B is the same.
Remark 2. We may generalize the construction given in Pervin [p.158, l.$-$12--l.$-$2] by replacing $\{r_n\in \mathbb{N}|n\ge 3\}$ with any countable dense set $D$ of real numbers in $(0,1)$. Then the construction given in Dugundji [p.147, l.10--l.26] will be a special case of this generalized construction.
Remark 3. Locally compact $\Rightarrow$ Completely regular [Dugundji [p.311, diagram]], so we cannot use B or C to prove D. A remedy is to require that one of the two closed sets be compact. Rudin [p.38, Theorem 2.7] corresponds Dugundji [p.144, 3.2(2)]. The construction given in Rudin [p.40, l.$-$9--p.41, l.4] is similar to that given in Pervin [p.158, l.$-$12--l.$-$2] except that $r<s \Rightarrow c(G_r)\subset G_s$ [The larger a rational number is, the larger the corresponding set is; Pervin [p.158, l.$-$11]] is different from Rudin [p.41, (3)][The larger a rational number is, the smaller the corresponding set is]. The continuity of $\mathfrak{g}$ [Pervin [p.158, l.$-$1; p.159, l.9]] is proved by a direct argument, while the continuity of $f$ [Rudin [p.41, l.5--l.12]] is proved by an indirect [through semiconcontinuity] and more generalized argument; the direction of generalization: continuity $\rightarrow$ semicontinuity.
For the applications of Urysohn’s lemma, see Example 6.169 and Example 6.170 in https://sites.google.com/view/lcwangpress/%E9%A6%96%E9%A0%81/papers/mathematical-methods.