# The usage of induction in the proof of Urysohn's lemma

Tags: general-topology

**[Proof taken from]:** Kelley's book "General Topology".

> If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint closed subsets of a normal space $X$, then there is a continuous function $f$ on $X$ to the interval $[0,1]$ such that $f$ is zero on $A$ and one on $B$.

The proof is structured as follows (here $F(-)$ will be a family of sets in $X$):

1. Let $D$ the set of positive dyadic rational numbers. For $t$ in $D$ and $t > 1$ let $F(t) = X$, let $F(1) = X - B$ and let $F(0)$ be an open set containing $A$ such that cl$(F(0))$ is disjoint from $B$.
   (This part is clear)

2.For $t$ in $D$ and $0 < t < 1$ write $t$ in the form $t = (2m+1)2^{-n}$ and choose, inductively on $n$, $F(t)$ to be an open set containing cl$(F(2m2^{-n}))$ and such that cl$(F(t)) \subseteq F((2m+2)2^{-n}))$. This choice is possible because $X$ is normal.

Here there are my problems...
How exactly does he use induction? And what exactly is the the role of $m$ during this operation? Please, is there someone that could explain me all the details regarding this point?
I would to specify that:

- I found another related topic here ([Urysohn's Lemma: Proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106917/urysohns-lemma-proof?rq=1)), but I actually don't understand more or less the fourth line of the proof (which is exactly my problem);
- I know that there are a lot of variants of this proof (for example the one on the book by Munkres, or another one on the classic by Rudin), but I strongly prefer to understand this one;
- I have searched on the web, but without finding any *detailed* explanation;

3. Let $f(x)  = \inf\{t : x \in F(t) \}$. The previous lemma shows that $f$ is continuous. Furthermore, the function is zero on $A$ and one on $B$ [some related considerations]. (This part is clear).

Thank you very much for any hint/help/advice!
Cheers

Comment: Some books ,e.g,by Simmons and by Engelking, call this the Tietze-Urysohn lemma (or theorem), and  refer to the case where A or B contains a single point as Urysohn's lemma.

Comment: Dear @user254665, I didn't know before - thank you for the clarification :-)

Comment: Perhaps weirdly (for a non-category theory guy) I found the ncatlab page on Urysohn's lemma very helpful in 'grokking' the intuition of the construction.  In particular there's a marvelous picture there which is very helpful. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Urysohn%27s+lemma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The induction goes as follows.

Step 1:
Define $F(1/2)$ using $F(0)$ and $F(1)$.

Step 2:
Define $F(1/4)$ using $F(0)$ and $F(1/2)$.
Define $F(3/4)$ using $F(1/2)$ and $F(1)$.

Step 3:
Define $F(1/8)$ using $F(0)$ and $F(1/4)$.
Define $F(3/8)$ using $F(1/4)$ and $F(1/2)$.
Define $F(5/8)$ using $F(1/2)$ and $F(3/4)$.
Define $F(7/8)$ using $F(3/4)$ and $F(1)$.

etc. (I assume the pattern is clear.)

At each step the definition of $F$ depends on values of $F$ defined in previous steps, and sometimes the definitions of $F(0)$ and $F(1)$ already made.

In the proof, we're defining $F(t)$ where $t=(2m+1)2^{-n}$. Note the $2m+1$ ensures the numerator of the fraction $\frac{2m+1}{2^n}$ is odd, so that $t$ can't be written with a lower power of $2$ in the denominator. (Example: if we're in Step 3, $n=3$ and $m=0,1,2$, or $3$.)

Given this, the values of $F$ at $(2m)2^{-n}$ and $(2m+2)2^{-n}$ have already been defined in previous steps, because both of these can be written with smaller powers of $2$ in the denominator (at most $2^{n-1}$ in the denominator, but sometimes even smaller, for example, in the $n=3$, $m=2$ case, $(2m)2^{-n}=\frac48=\frac12$).

So there is no problem with the induction.

Comment: Thank you for you help! I understand your clarification, but unfortunately there are another two fundamental points I think I am missing (again with step 2). Let's consider the statement "This choice is possible because X is normal". Please...could you help me here, again? Furthermore, I would to prove rigorously that if $t, s$ are two dyadic number with $t < s$, then $F(t) \subseteq F(s)$. It should be a direct and almost evident consequence of their definition...but when I try to formalize this fact in a clearly way, I feel a bit confused. Thank you anyway!!!

Comment: Normality ensures that if you have a closed set $C$ sitting inside an open set $V$, then you can find an open set $U$ such that $C\subseteq U\subseteq\overline{U}\subseteq V$. In defining $F(t)$, we're thinking of $\operatorname{cl}(F(2m2^{-n}))$ as $C$ and $F((2m+2)2^{-n})$ as $V$. The fact that $C\subseteq V$ here is a consequence of the previous induction steps.

Comment: Thank you, I understand almost the entire proof...except for a last "subtle" point. You suggest that the fact that $C \subseteq V$ is a consequence of the previous induction steps. I "agree" with you, in the sense that I "see" that it must be true, but I am trying (again) to prove it rigorously...but...unfortunately I am getting lost in the computation.
Please...do you mind giving me an hand again? :-)
So the remaining statement to clarify is "If $t < s$ are two dyadic numbers, then $F(t) \subseteq F(s)$".
Thanks in advance!

Comment: We're in the middle of Step $n$. Either $F(2m2^{-n})$ or $F((2m+2)2^{-n})$ was defined in Step $n-1$. This is because $2m2^{-n}$ and $(2m+2)2^{-n}$ differ by $2^{n-1}$. Say it was $F(2m2^{-n})$ that was defined in the previous step. Then it was defined so that its closure was contained in $F((2m+2)2^{-n})$, which is exactly what we need here. The other possibility leads to the same conclusion. If this confuses you, I would think about what I am saying here in the context of Steps 1, 2, and 3.

Comment: After Step $n$, you know that $F(0\cdot 2^{-n})\subseteq F(1\cdot 2^{-n})\subseteq\cdots\subseteq F(2^n\cdot 2^{-n})$. Then, given any dyadic numbers $0\leq s<t\leq 1$, you can find $n$ large enough so that $s=m_1\cdot 2^{-n}$ and $t=m_2\cdot 2^{-n}$. Then what I just stated implies $F(s)\subseteq F(t)$.

Comment: Two comments above I meant "differ by $2^{-(n-1)}$".

Comment: Thank you, I'll think on it. (I still don't manage to write a rigorous and complete proof that covers all the possible cases, although I should understand what you mean in the previous comments).

Answer (score 0):

Kelley is defining $F(t)$ for $t=(2m+1)2^{-n}$ in terms of two "previous" $F(t)$ involving $n-1$, namely $t=2m2^{-n}=m2^{-(n-1)}$ and $t=(2m+2)2^{-n}=(m+1)2^{-(n-1)}$.

It helps to write out the procedure for $n=1$, then $n=2$, and so on. So having defined $F(0)$ and $F(1)$, you then define $F(1/2)$ (i.e., $n=1$, and $m=0$), then you define $F(1/4)$ and $F(3/4)$ (i.e., $n=2$, $m=0, 1$), and so on.

The value of $m\in \{0, 1, \ldots,2^{n-1}-1\}$ is there to specify which dyadic $t$ you are working on. In the induction step $n-1\to n$, the value $m$ is generic.

Comment: Dear @grand_chat, thank you for your interest! Now there is only a last step that I need to understand before concluding...do you mind having a look at the comment above? Thank you in advance.