# Properties of rational numbers used in Munkres proof of Urysohn's lemma (Step-$1$, Step-$2$, Step-$3$)

Tags: general-topology

In the first step, it involves constructing a sequence of open sets $\{U_n \}$ indexed by some re-sequencing of rational numbers $\{P_i \}$ of a topological space $X$ with the property, when $p<q$, that :

$$ U_p \subset U_q$$

(1)**For constructing these sets, we arrange the set of all rational numbers in the set $\left[0,1 \right]$ into an infinite sequence in with the first two entries being $1$ and $0$. Munkres' say this is done for convenience, but I don't understand how this is so.**  To clarify more, my doubt is why Munkre's went out of his way to make $1$ and $0$ the first two terms.

Now , another issue , (2)**later $P_i$ is considered as consisting of the first $n$ rational number in the sequence. For the set $P_{n+1} = P_n \cup \{r \}$, it is said that $r$ has an immediate predecessor $p$ in $P_{n+1}$ and an immediate succesor $q$ in $P_{n+1}$. This defies my common sense, because, what if $r$ is larger than every other element in $P_n$ or small than?**  [(Related)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4463603/urysohn-lemma-in-munkres-topology)

Also, my last doubt is regarding how this proof helps us actually prove the proof of the statement of Urysohn lemma.

> Urysohn's lemma: Let $X$ be a normal space, let $A$ and $B$ be disjoint closed subsets of $X$ . Let $\left[a,b \right]$ be a closed interval in the real line. Then there exists a continous map
>
> $$ f: X \to \left[ a, b \right]$$
>
> Such that $f(x)=a$ for every $ x \in A$ , and $f(x) = b $ for every $ x \in B$

Now here is the definition of function given in step-3:

$$ f(x) = \text{inf} Q(x) = \text{inf} \{ p | x \in U_p \}$$

**(3)Now, the possible set of values for $p$ is actually rational number. So, how does the infimum help turn the function into a real valued one? Maybe this is trivial to understand if one had intuition for inf but I think some more details may help.**

---

Btw I have linked every helpful MSE post on the Urysohn Lemma's proof based on Munkres onto this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106917/urysohns-lemma-proof?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Do you understand that the set of rational numbers is countable? And that every subset of a countable set is also countable? If you do, then question 1 should have an immediate answer.

Comment: My concern is mainly with $1$ and $0$ being first two entries. It being a sequence of rational number is fine. @LeeMosher

Comment: Well, in that case, start with any sequence that enumerates the rational numbers in $[0,1]$. And then, like any two terms of any sequence, you can reorder the sequence to put $1$ and $0$ as the first two terms.

Comment: I mean my question is why is it convenient to put 1 and 0 as first two terms? @LeeMosher

Comment: Then you should perhaps clarify the wording. You can see from my comments and from the one answer (so far) that your wording on 1 is difficult to understand.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4463603/861687) might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

For (1): the rationals are countably infinite, as are those within $[0,1]$. Formally that means there is some given bijection $\psi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ (in fact, there are loads!). We don’t really care about the exact nature of $\psi$, but Munkres wants an easy notational access to $0,1$. As $\psi$ bijects, there are distinct and unique naturals $n,m$ with $\psi(n)=0,\psi(m)=1$. There are also, as $\psi$ injects, distinct rationals $p=\psi(1),q=\psi(2)$. Let $\varphi:\Bbb N\to\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$ be given as follows: $$k\overset{\varphi}{\mapsto}\begin{cases}0&k=1\\1&k=2\\p&k=n\\q&k=m\\\psi(k)&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$You can see that $\varphi$ is a bijection. So, we can enumerate the rationals in $[0,1]$ by the sequence $\{r_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$, with law $r_n:=\varphi(n)$, and the first two entries of this sequence are $0,1$. In this manner, you can arrange the elements of a countable enumeration to appear in a lot of different, prescribed orders. I could, arbitrarily, demand the $123456789$th element of the sequence to be $1/(123456789)$, just for fun.

For (2): the question does not make sense to me. If $r$ is the $(n+1)$th element of the sequence, then $r$ has a predecessor in $P_n$, namely the $n$th element of the sequence, but it doesn’t have a successor in $P_{n+1}$ since the next, $(n+2)$th element would be in $P_{n+2}$... perhaps I misunderstand what you mean by successor/predecessor. Please elaborate on how Munkres uses this idea, so I can see what is actually meant.

For (3): two points. Firstly, any rational-valued function can automatically be viewed as real valued. Secondly, this function is not actually rational-valued. If I understand the context correctly, it is a continuous real function - long ago, I asked about Royden’s construction of the same function, and I will link that post if you wish. The infimum of some set of rationals might be irrational: consider $\inf_{r\in\Bbb Q}\{r>\sqrt{2}\}=\sqrt{2}$. What this function is doing (perhaps Munkres differs notably from Royden on this point, I don’t know without further details from you - but I doubt it), is getting a handle on the smallest open set $U_p$ which contains the element $x$. However, such a “smallest” $U_p$ might not exist among the collection of $U_p$, as is often the case when one deals with (continuous) infinities (what is the smallest rational $x$, $x>1$? No such $x$ exists). So, we take a limit, an infimum, and it may happen (and *does* happen) that the value is sometime irrational. The $U_p$ are arranged such that this limiting process produces a nice continuous function with image $[0,1]$. As a concrete example, consider the context of the Euclidean subspace $[0,1]$. If the $U_p:=[0,p)$ for rational $p\in[0,1)$, and $U_1:=[0,1]$, then what is: $$\inf_p\{1/e\in U_p\}$$It is in fact just $1/e$. Indeed, the function $f(x)$ thus constructed would end up being the identity map.

Comment: Thanks. I'll tidy up 2 when I get on my pc again.

Comment: " then r has a predecessor in Pn, namely the nth element of the sequence, but"... hmm they didn't say the sequence is kept strictly increasing afaik

Comment: Also in step-3 how do we know that every irrational has such a set for it? Also in step-1, my question is regarding those two were kept as first two elements not on the numeration. I understand that you can numerate rationals with naturals well

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom I suspect “predecessor of $r$” as meaning: “the previous element to $r$ in the enumeration” (i.e., if $r$ is element $n$, we ask for element $(n-1)$) not “largest element of the enumeration, smaller than $r$”. Because, for any rational $r$, there is no such thing as a $q\in\Bbb Q$, with $q<r$ and $p\in\Bbb Q,p<r\implies p\le q$. But again, please explain how Munkres uses the notion of predecessor and successor, because I am having to guess. With regards to step 1, you ask how Munkres can have $0,1$ as the first elements. I explicitly gave you a way to arrange this.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom For your comment regarding $3$. We know that $f$ is continuous, and that it attains $0$ and $1$. By the intermediate value theorem, it necessarily attains every element $0<t<1$, whether or not $t$ is irrational. However, there is no “corresponding set” for an irrational - that is precisely why an infimum must be taken, to make this work. The $U_p$ are rational-indexed, so no irrational $t$ can find itself a $U_t$. However, it *can* find a sequence of $U_{p_1},U_{p_2},...$ where $p_k\to t$ from above, which might help you make sense of it.

Comment: No... my question is not how he put 0,1 as first .I appreciate you giving the way to construct the sequence, but my question was **why** is he doing it? How is it convenient

Comment: I think I need to think more of step -3. And I will check the step-2 thing. I guess it may be because he is using the word in different sense as you said @FShirke

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom Ah I see. Well, I can’t speak for Munkres without seeing their original text (I don’t have a copy) but I can tell you that *Royden*, Royden created the $U_p$ by induction. The induction had to begin with $U_0,U_1$ for convenience: it’s convenient because it’s just... nice. The human mind appreciates beginning at zero and ending at one. If we began at $1/40$, it might be hard to visualise where $U_0$ ends up. The $U_0,U_1$ played the important role of covering the two disjoint closed sets that define the Urysohn function.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom In fact, there’s nothing special whatsoever about using $[0,1]$. We could just as well use $[-123456789,1/\lfloor e^e^e^e\rfloor]$. *It’s just that $[0,1]$ is nice*

Comment: @FShrike predecessor and successor notion used to describe order in $P=\Bbb{Q}\cap [0,1]$. $r=x_i$, for some $i\geq 3$. So $\exists p,q\in P_n$ such that $0\leq p\lt r\lt q\leq 1$. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4463603/861687), it is not a proof by induction.

Comment: @user264745 I never claimed it was a proof by induction. I just wanted Tryst to explain how the terms were being used, in order for their question to be answerable. Imho Munkres makes it too complicated: Paul Frost’s answer needed a Zorn-type argument. In Royden, we make do with dyadic rationals, which has an easy induction argument, and we are done very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The convenience in (1) is that it ensures that you needn't worry about (2).
I.e. $r$ cannot be larger, or smaller, than all the elements of $P_n$ because they include 0 and 1. Without that assumption he would need to include the cases where $r$ is extremal - it's easily done but unnecessary.