# On step-4 of Munkres' proof of the Urysohn lemma

Tags: general-topology

In this question my reference is the book *Topology* by Munkres. The proof of Urysohn's lemma can be found in section 33. In the last step of the proof, the author says:

> Now we prove continuity of $f$. Given a point $x_{0}$ of $X$ and an open interval $(c, d)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ containing the point $f\left(x_{0}\right)$, we wish to find a neighborhood $U$ of $x_{0}$ such that $f(U) \subset(c, d)$. Choose rational numbers $p$ and $q$ such that
> $$
> c<p<f\left(x_{0}\right)<q<d .
> $$
> We assert that the open set $U=U_{q}-\bar{U}_{p}$ is the desired neighborhood of $x_{0}$.

My question is: what if $\bar U_p=U_q$ and thus $U=\varnothing$? The book's inductive construction of the sets $\left\{U_p:p\in[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q\right\}$ doesn't seem to exclude this possibility:

> Let $P$ be the set of all rational numbers in $[0,1]$. Since $P$ is countable, we may list numbers in $P$ as an infinite sequence, and for convenience we may assume that the first two numbers are $1$ and $0$. First we shall define $U_1=X-B$. Now, $A$ is a closed set contained in the open set $U_1$, so by normality of $X$ we may choose an open set $U_0$ such that $A\subset U_0$ and $\bar U_0\subset U_1$.
>
> In general, let $P_n$ be the first $n$ rational numbers in the infinite sequence, and assume that $U_p$ has been defined for all $p\in P_n$, satisfying the condition that
> $$
> p<q\quad\Rightarrow\quad \bar U_p\subset U_q.
> $$
> Let $r$ be the next rational number following $P_n$, and we want to define $U_r$. Since $P_n$ is finite and $r$ is neither $0$ nor $1$, $r$ must have an immediate predecessor $p$ and successor $q$ in $P_n$. Since $\bar U_p$ is a closed set contained in the open set $U_q$, we may find by normality of $X$ an open set, defined to be $U_r$, such that $\bar U_p\subset U_r$ and $\bar U_r\subset U_q$. We assert that the above relation now holds for every pair of elements of $P_{n+1}$. If both elements lie in $P_{n}$, then the condition holds by the induction hypothesis. If one of them is $r$ and the other is a point $s$ of $P_{n}$, then either $s \leq p$ or $s \geq q$, so
> $$
> \bar{U}_{s} \subset \bar{U}_{p} \subset U_{r}~~~(s\le p),\qquad \bar{U}_{r} \subset U_{q} \subset U_{s}~~~(s\ge q)
> $$
> In both cases the condition is satisfied, so $U_p$ has been defined for all $p\in P_{n+1}$. By induction it has been defined for all $p\in P$.

Connectedness of the space $X$ seems irrelevant here. But if $X$ is disconnected, it is possible that $\bar U_p=U_q$. Any insight is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remember the definition of $f(x_0)$ as the infimum $r$ such that $x_0\in U(r)$. If you have that equality, then we will also have $U_s=U_q$ for the rationals $s$ with $p<s<f(x_0)<q$. The definition of $f$ would require $f(x_0)$ to be strictly smaller than what it is.

Comment: @user85667 I see. Your argument should work. However I'm suspicious about the following: the construction of the sets $\left\{U_p\right\}$ does not involve the function $f$, yet you used $f$ to prove that the equality never holds. How does the **construction** of the sets prevent such a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right, the construction does not prevent $\overline U_p = U_q$ for $p < q$. As an example take any disconnected normal space $X$. Let $X = A \cup B$ with disjoint non-empty closed subsets $A, B$. Then $U_1 = A$ and $U_0 = A$ and Munkres' construction shows that all $U_p = A$.

But, as user85667 comments, the essential point is the construction of $f$ via the sets $U_p$. The definition is
$$f(x) = \inf \{ r \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q \mid x \in U_r \} .$$
Thus

1. $f(x) < q$ implies $x \in U_q$:
   There exists $r \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ such that $r < q$ and $x \in U_r$. But $U_r \subset \overline U_r \subset U_q$, thus $x \in U_q$.
2. If $f(x) > p$, then $x \notin \overline U_p$:
   Choose $r \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ such that $f(x) > r > p$. Then $x \notin U_r \supset \overline U_p$, thus $x \notin \overline U_p$.

For $p,q \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q $ such that $p < f(x_0) < q$ we therefore get $x_0 \in U_q \setminus \overline U_p$, in particular $\overline U_p \subsetneqq U_q$.

Let us now look at the above example of a disconnected $X$. For $x \in A$ we have $f(x) = 0$ and for $x \in B$ we have $f(x) = 1$. There is no $x$ such that $0 < f(x) < 1$, so we do not have a problem.